# What should the table do when using multicolumn multiple times?

Tags: tables, tabularx, two-column

I want to get a form like this：
[image: tu]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{makecell} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multirow{2}{*}{B} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{C} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{D} &\\
    \cline{3-5}
    &x&y&z
    \cline{6-8}
    &x&y&z \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But when using multicolumn twice, you will get an error：

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{frame}
```

What should I do?

Comment: These are environments: you dropped \begin and \end, see e.g. https://ctan.joethei.xyz/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf // Also, when we copy your code, it will never compile …

Comment: @MS-SPO Thank you, I have corrected it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two syntax errors in your code. To get rid of them, you need to

- remove the `&` particle from `\multicolumn{3}{c}{D} &\\`
- not alternate between `\cline` directives and column contents. Hence, do replace

  ```
       \cline{3-5}
        &x&y&z
       \cline{6-8}
        &x&y&z \\ \hline
  ```

  with

  ```
       \cline{3-5} \cline{6-8}
       && x&y&z & x&y&z \\ \hline
  ```

With these changes, your code will compile. However, the resulting "look" may not be to your liking, as the two `\cline`s will be joined together.

I'd like to suggest that you switch to using the line-drawing macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package instead of using `\hline` and `\cline`.

[image]

Note that I can see no compelling need for the `\multirow` directives in the OP's code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{@{} *{8}{c} @{}}
   \toprule
   A & B & \multicolumn{3}{c}{C} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{D} \\
   \cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(l){6-8} 
   && u&v&w & x&y&z \\
   \midrule
   \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I corrected it

Comment: @ZhaoDazhuang - You're most welcome.